# PHP - parsing src attribute of <img> tag in string

Tags: php, regex, parsing, src

What would be the simplest but reliable way to parse the `src` attribute of the first `<img>` tag found in an arbitrary text string, but without using any external libraries? That means to get everything that is between opening and closing `"` character of `<img>` tag's `src` atrribute.

---

I did this script, but it is not a reliable solution in some cases:

```
  $string = $item['description'];
  $arr = explode('img', $string);
  $arr = explode('src', $arr[1]);
  $arr = explode('=', $arr[1]);
  $arr = explode('>', $arr[1]);

  $pos1 = strpos($arr[0], '"')+1;
  $pos2 = strrpos($arr[0], '"')-1;

  if (!$pos1) {
    $pos1 = strpos($arr[0], "'")+1;
    $pos2 = strrpos($arr[0], "'")-1;
  }

  if ($pos1 && $pos2) { 
    $result = substr($arr[0], $pos1, $pos2); 
  }
  else { $result = null; }
```

Comment: [`DOMDocument`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) is not an external library, why not use it? Use `getElementsByTagName()`, grab the first item, and get the `src` with `$img->getAttribute('src')`.

Comment: It is possible that DOMDocument will be unavailable at some servers?

Comment: DOMDocument is a PHP built-in class.

Comment: Ok, will try, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only safest way is by using `DOMDocument` built-in (in PHP 5) class. Use `getElementsByTagName()`, check if the length is more than 0, and grab the first item `src` value with `getAttribute('src')`:

```
$html = "YOUR_HTML_STRING";
$dom = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8');
$dom->loadHTML($html, LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED | LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD);
$imgs = $dom->getElementsByTagName('img');
if ($imgs->length > 0) {
    echo $imgs->item(0)->getAttribute('src');
}
```

See [this PHP demo](https://ideone.com/Gu3zyM)

Answer (score 2):

If You want to get the values of all attributes of img tag, You need to make 2 regular expressions.

1. Get content of an img tag:

```
/<\s*img([^<>]+)>/
```

2. Then use this regex on the captured content with function [preg_match_all()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php)

   ```
   /\S+\s*=\s*[\'\"]([^\"\']+)[\'\"]/g
   ```

Answer (score 2):

Here is your answer: 
First, you need to make call to this regex,

```
<img(.*?)>
```

Then, in order to get other attributes, you need to make another regex call to the previous result

```
"(.*?)"
```

Comment: And if there are other attributes in the tag?

Answer (score 1):

Try This,

```
<img\s+src\s?\=\s?\"(https?\:\/\/[\w\.\/]+)\".*\/>
```